# Have any major US book publisher published a book about USA war crimes?

Tags: united-states, war, war-crime

There are some books from non USA book publisher and some indie and self-published books.

But I was unable to find a book that would be published by a major US book publisher and the book was not a fiction but a historical book bashing US for their war crimes from killing native Indians to the war in Iraq and Afghanistan.

Comment: This appears to be a request for references, which is discouraged. It also appears to be subjective (what is a major book publisher). I'm not entirely sure it is within scope for H:SE.  Could you rescope the question to be more clearly within the guidelines?

Comment: How exactly is the war in Afghanistan a war crime? How would you react when not one but 3 of your landmarks has just been attacked and destroyed? Even the most hippy of presidents would have to consider armed action lest they commit career suicide.

Comment: @SchwitJanwityanujit I don't discuss with people who support imperialism, sorry.

Comment: LOL OK so a retaliatory attack is considered 'imperialism', not to mention how Afghanistan's mineral concessions were sold largely to...Chinese companies. I think we know full well now what your motives are on this website. FYI, I consider the Iraq war 'imperialism'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that you are basically asking if USA sources ever publish histories that are either cheifly about, or at least include, some of the more unsavory, or even downright immoral conduct of the United States throughout its history.

The answer to that has to be an unequivocal **yes**. The temptation here is to produce a list (which is outside of the bounds of this stack), but I will point you to probably the most well-known and comprehensive exemplar: [A People's History of the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_People%27s_History_of_the_United_States). This is a work written by American Historian [Howard Zinn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_People%27s_History_of_the_United_States), and published by American publisher [Harper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harper_&_Row), and can be found in pretty much any library or large bookstore in the USA.

While being perhaps the most comprehensive, it is far from the only American work of history or nonfiction covering what might be considered "bad" behavior on the part of the United States. Any bookstore or library in the USA with a non-fiction section is full of such works. Much of the reason their past history of things like native genocides, slavery, racisim, domestic terrorisim, improper wartime behavior, etc., is so well known to the world at large is because of American authors and American publishers.

If anything, it would be much fairer to wonder why other societies aren't nearly as embracing of self-criticisim as the USA is.

Comment: Are you speaking about the.... UK?

Comment: @Derfder - No naming names, but there are large modern countries out there that have things like, say Armenian genocides or Nanking Massacres in their history, and refuse to admit (or let anyone within their borders admit) the incident even occurred. Perhaps the USA can be *too* self-critical somtimes, which might make it look worse at large than they deserve. But between those two poles, I'd rather err on that side. How can you possibly make your society a better one if you can't even admit you've done things wrong?

Comment: I agree with you completely.

Comment: @T.E.D. Perhaps this shows the confidence of the Americans in their destiny. A confident people are likely to tolerate and even encourage self-criticism. What do you think?

Comment: @Arani hmm, they didn't apologized to the native American Indians in an official speech made by a president. I don't think they have apologized for Vietnam war either. In the contrary almost every country in the Europe that killed the Jews apologized to them in the official speech/statement etc.

Comment: @Derfder - Official  goverment "apologies" in the USA are problematic due to **legal liability issues**. For example, if the Federal Government were to say "The Trail of Tears was illegal and unjust and we shouldn't have done it", then the Cherokee Tribe could quite plausably go to court and claim they legally own all land in Georgia (we are talking Trillions of dollars of property here). That doesn't stop the general public from seeing and acknowleging that the [Trail of Tears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_of_Tears) was in fact illegal and unjust and should not have been done.

Comment: In Europe many countries must pay a lot of money to the Jews as reparations. There were courts (or in most cases automatically) and they must pay to the Jews. Why not pay reparations to the Indians?

Comment: If there could be created Israel in the 20th century, why not Independent Indian states in the 21th century. After all, it's the land of the free ;D. If they would go via Kickstarter or Indiegogo I might send them some chips to re-create e.g. Cherokee Republic ;)

Comment: @Derfder - We're getting off into the weeds here. I suggest either taking this to chat, or posting your new questions as actual questions rather than comments.